# How to test enzyme, react-virtualized, material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme, react-virtualized

I have to test a very unusual case, in my test I should click to some component which is wrapped by  from material-ui and it is inside the List from react-vertualized.

I have dived to it -

```
wrapper
  .find(TreeView)
  .dive()
  .find(AutoSizer)
  .renderProp('children', {})
  .find(VirtualizedTree)
  .dive()
  .renderProp('rowRenderer', { index: 0, props: {...} });
```

And if I debug it I see this result -

```
<WithStyles(TreeNode) data-test="projected-tree" components={{...}} onSelectToggle={[Function]} onExpandToggle={[Function]} width={...} style={...} node={{...}} level={0} isOdd={true} />
```

The component which I want to click is inside the TreeNode, but when I try to dive I receive the error related to my custom theme which I use in my project, this happening because  has lost the connection to the custom theme.

I think this happening because it has been rendered through the `rowRenderer` property of List.

Maybe somebody has any ideas on how to pass the custom theme inside the List.rowRenderer?

Comment: could you paste the error message you're receiving?  also I would assume you can use withTheme: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#how-do-i-combine-the-withstyles-and-withtheme-hocs

Comment: The error message is very specific to my case `can not find property "white" of undefined`, property `white` is a color in my custom theme, my theme has custom property `customColors` and inside it has property `white`, so my custom theme has been lost, is I debug the theme which I receive and it is default material-ui theme.

Comment: hmm, how does the code for using the theme look like and how does the initialization of the component in the test look like?

Comment: `shallowWithIntl(
<MuiThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>{element}</MuiThemeProvider>
).instance().getChildContext();`

Comment: Yes, I'm also using react-intl here

Comment: And rendering of item - http://jsfiddle.net/chg3s5vd/
The problem is with `TreeNode`

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to test react-virtualized with enzyme?

Answer (score 0):

you need to mock the width and height to make AutoSizer return a width to children can showup
you can use this function mockOffsetSize

```
  // AutoSizer uses offsetWidth and offsetHeight.
  // Jest runs in JSDom which doesn't support measurements APIs.
  function mockOffsetSize(width, height) {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight', {
      configurable: true,
      value: height,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', {
      configurable: true,
      value: width,
    });
  }
```

ref: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/AutoSizer/AutoSizer.jest.js#L68